# Does dark matter exist because as Einstein said the laws of physics should be the same inside and outside a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, dark-matter

Spacetime is said to be time like inside a black hole ( two events can happen at the same place at different times). Spacetime is called space- like outside a black hole ( two events can happen simultaneously at different places outside the hole.
Albert Einstein didn't think the laws of physics should change like this. I am asking : could dark matter be created by a collapsing star so that neutrons don't speed up too much as they fall into the hole because the energy they should have gained from gravity is used to create dark matter .This could mean that because neutrons haven't sped up that for them gravity doesn't get stronger and spacetime remains space like as Einstein would have wanted. Is there anything obviously wrong with this idea - are there experimental observations that could rule it out?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: no.

The reason is that there is no mechanism preventing matter from speeding when falling into a black hole (it cannot move faster than light according to the local light cones, even though they are weirdly tilted according to an outside observer), and that there is much more dark matter than there has ever been stars or black holes.

Black holes are defined using Einstein's physics, and the reason their interiors work as they do is exactly that general relativity is assumed to be valid inside and outside the event horizon.

Comment: If the entire universe collapsed then the gravitational energy could become greater than the mass/ energy of all the stars and black holes. Any dark matter created by my proposed mechanism would be dispersed by inflation to create galaxies.